# I can run a script locally, but cannot do "ssh HOSTNAME /path/to/script.sh"

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, bash, environment-variables

I have a linux server, and a linux desktop.

I have written the following simple script to dump the database of a django web application:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -o errexit

cd $(dirname $0)

. virtualenv/bin/activate

cd mysite

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings.my_hostname"
django-admin.py dumpdata --settings=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE > database.json
```

The programme `django-admin.py` requires the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environmental variable to work properly.

If I ssh into the machine, `ssh HOSTNAME`, and then run the script `/var/www/example.com/dumper.sh` from the bash terminal on the remote host, and everything works fine. I get no output (as expected), and the file `database.json` is there and has the right data.

However (on my linux desktop), I cannot run this command: "ssh HOSTNAME /var/www/example.com/dumper.sh`` and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db import connections, router, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.my_hostname' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings.my_hostname
```

It's as if the `export` command isn't being run, or isn't taking effect.

Why doesn't this work? (Or alternatively *should* it work? Am I mistaken in thinking that this should work?)

### Update №1

On @faker's suggestion, I put `echo $PATH` in the script before the call to `django-admin.py`. The `. virtualenv/bin/activate` changes the shell path. I get a path of `/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games` when I run it via `ssh HOSTNAME /path/to/script.sh`, and after logging in I get `/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/bin:/home/rory/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games`. The only difference is the `~/bin` part, but I did a `which django-admin.py` aswell, and in both instances it's using `/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/bin/django-admin.py` so in both instances it's using the same programme for the `django-admin.py` command.

### Update №2

On @Andrew Schulman's advice of the same, but for `$PYTHONPATH`. PYTHONPATH was empty in both cases. However I added `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'` instead of just `echo $PYTHONPATH`, and got different results.

When I ssh into HOSTNAME and run script manually (the one that works):

```
['', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg', '/var/www/example.com/mysite', '/home/rory/code/python/lib', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

When I invoke the script over ssh (this doesn't work):

```
['', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/var/www/example.com/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

The working version has a `/var/www/example.com/mysite`. The settings file is located in `/var/www/example.com/mysite/settings/my_hostname.py`. This makes sense since the working invokcation can load the file.

Why isn't the 'remotely invoked' version getting that on it's python path?

Comment: Try `ssh HOSTNAME "echo $PATH"` and compare it with `echo $PATH` from a shell where running django-admin.py works. Is it different?

Comment: Do the same as above with $PYTHONPATH.  Note the message from Python on the last line:  `Could not import settings 'settings.my_hostname' (Is it on sys.path?)`

Answer (score 2):

Change your script and put `-l` after the shebang. so `#!/bin/bash -l`

Alternatively change your ssh command to `ssh HOSTNAME bash -l /var/www/example.com/dumper.sh`

Rationale:
When you run `ssh HOSTNAME command` instead of just `ssh HOSTNAME`, the shell used to launch `command` is not a 'login' shell, and so different scripts get called (See the INVOCATION section of `man bash`) which results in your environment being setup differently.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. I got the same output if I put a ``-l`` in the shebang line, or used ``ssh HOSTNAME -l …``

Comment: No, `ssh HOSTNAME bash -l ...`, you need to put the 'bash' there

Comment: I mistyped. I used ``ssh HOSTNAME bash -l /path/to/script.sh`` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that you need to quote the bash line for it to recognize the -l properly, like this:

ssh HOSTNAME "bash -l /path/to/script.sh"

Answer (score 1):

When running cmd over ssh in one line, the .profile is not read.
To test, try this:

```
ssh host env
```

Use this instead to fix this issue (quotes are compulsory):

```
ssh host '. ~/.profile; cmd'
```

eg:

```
ssh HOSTNAME '. ~/.bashrc; /var/www/example.com/dumper.sh'
```